# $('body').html() gave blank content from response data that come from $jQuery.post in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, struts-1

I got this javascript code in a JSP:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var act = $('#myForm').attr('action') + '&act=' + $('#submitBtn').val();

    var dataStr = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $.post(act, dataStr, function(data, status) {
        $('body').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The facts:

1. I'm using jquery v1.3.x (and I can't replace with newer version because of company policy).
2. The jsp is in a pop-up window.
3. There is a submit button with id=submitBtn
4. When the submit button is clicked, it will execute above code and send the data into struts action.
5. The action url:

   someAction.do?someParam=blabla&someNo=213354345&mode=POP&act=Update Your Data

   (note: I had replaced some sensitive data, but the argument pattern is same)
6. The problem is at this line:

   **$('body').html(data);**

   It produces Error: **NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure** in error console. I heard it's related with cross domain request, but my application is at localhost, how could it happened?

In IE 8, it successfully replaced the current page content with the **data** value (which is html string). But in firefox (v22), it gave blank page, I checked with right click -> View Source, it's really empty. Then I checked with firebug, the response **data** indeed contains the result html page string. If I debug with alert(data); before the $('body').html() call, it also show the html string.

So the **$.post()** function successfully returns the response data but it seems the **$('body').html()** function failed to render the data.

So what is actually happened? I'm really have no clue.

What is the solution for this?

**UPDATE:**

I checked the error console, I got this error after submitted the page:

```
Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure
Source File: http://localhost:8080/myapp/script/jquery.js
Line: 19
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I debug the java code, I found out that the input html tag in the JSP that has indexed array name like this:

```
myItem[0].name
myItem[1].name
...
```

were not successfully submitted to the ActionForm class. I investigated the source of problem might come from a 3rd party javascript library.

Comment: _"I checked with right click -> View Source, it's really empty"_ - The View Source option shows the page source as originally returned from the server when the page first opened, i.e., before any dynamic updates.

Comment: Could you try $(document.body).html(data);

Comment: @Andrew: it gave same result: blank page

Comment: What's the result if you try $('body').empty().append(data); ?

Comment: @jAm: same, blank page :(

Comment: Can we get a url of the page or a duplicate?

Comment: @jAm: sure, see my question post.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log($('body'), data);` to make sure that both the jQuery object and data are as you expect?

Comment: @Khior: I never used console.log before, can you tell me when I have to run that command? If I tried run it after the blank page showed, I got: ``ReferenceError: data is not defined``

Comment: Btw, I saw in error console there is ``NS_ERROR_FAILURE`` error. What could that mean? I googled, it mostly said about cross domain request, but you can see at the url, my application is at localhost.

Comment: `Console.log()` prints it's parameter to the JavaScript console in your browser (press F12 in Firefox/IE/Chrome to make it appear). So if you put `console.log("Hello, world!");` you would see `Hello, world!` in the console. The line I provided in my previous comment should print out the jQuery object representing the body and also the data that is returned by the post request.

Comment: The most common cause of `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` is that the URL is incorrect or there is an error in the server code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41402/discussion-between-khior-and-suud)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $.post(act, dataStr, function(data) {
    document.body.innerHTML = data;
});
```

Comment: the result: it didn't gave blank page, but the page didn't change at all (like nothing happened), which means it also failed to render the response datda.